# php uploading files

Tags: php, uploading

I have problem with uploading files. Here is my form:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="transact.php" method="POST">
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>Nadpis:</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="<?php echo      htmlspecialchars($title); ?>" /></td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Text článku:</td>
 <td><textarea id="text" name="text" cols="55" rows="20"><?php if(!empty($a_text)) { echo htmlspecialchars($a_text); } ?></textarea></td>
 </tr><tr>
 <td>Obrázok k článku:</td>
 <td><input type="file" name="uploadfile" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td> </td>
 <td>
 <?php
 if ($_SESSION['access_level'] < 2) {
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'. $user_id. '"/>';
 }

 if(empty($article_id)) {
 echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Odoslat" />';
 } else {
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="' .$article_id. '"/>';
 echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Ulozit" />';
 }
 ?>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

when I run script transact.php I get error: **Notice: Undefined index: uploadfile in E:\xampp\htdocs\capitals\transact.php on line 138**
and when I type print_r($_FILES) i get just **Array()**
value of max upload size in php.ini file is set to 128 MB

my transact script:

```
      case 'Odoslat':
      session_start();
      $text = (isset($_POST['text']))? $_POST['text']: '';
      $nadpis = (isset($_POST['title']))? $_POST['title']: '';
      $image = (isset($_FILES['uploadfile']))?           imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']): '';


      print_r($_FILES); // it writes Array()
      if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($nadpis) && !empty($text) &&           $_FILES['uploadfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)   //here it indicates error
      {
      $ext = '.jpg';
      $query = 'INSERT INTO articles (article_id, user_id, a_text, title, submit_date)
      VALUES(NULL, '. $_SESSION['id']. ', "'. mysql_real_escape_string($text, $db). '", "'. 
      mysql_real_escape_string($nadpis, $db). '",  "' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s'). '")';
      mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
      $clanok_id = mysql_insert_id($db);
      $query = 'INSERT INTO foto (foto_id, article_id)
      VALUES (NULL, '. $clanok_id. ')';
      mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
      if(!empty($image))
      {
      $last_id = mysql_insert_id($db);
      $image_name = $last_id. $ext;
      imagejpeg($image, $dir. '/'. $image_name, 100);
      }
      else
      {
      $last_id = mysql_insert_id($db);
      $image_name = 'caps.jpg';
      }
      $priecinok = 'images/';
      $place = $priecinok. $image_name;
      $query = 'UPDATE foto 
      SET foto_path = "'. $place. '" WHERE foto_id = '. $last_id;
      mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
      $query = 'UPDATE articles 
      SET foto_id = '. $last_id. ' WHERE article_id = '. $clanok_id;
      mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

      $redirect = 'index.php';
      }

      else
      {
      $chyba = 'Nepodarilo sa nahrat clanok!';
      $redirect = 'index.php?chyba='. $chyba;
      }
      break;
```

Please how can I repare it? I will be very grateful if somebody help me...

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: what does your switch statement check for, show us the top of the file

Comment: here is the top of the file: if ($_REQUEST['action'])
{
switch($_REQUEST['action'])
{

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 things you should check in your php.ini file to make sure file uploads will work :

- **file_uploads** : should be set to 1
- **upload_max_filesize** : should be set to a value big enough for what you plan on uploading. You said it's set to 128 MB. Make sure it is written as '128M'.
- **post_max_size** : should be set to a value higher than upload_max_filesize since it includes the files and the other post data
- **max_file_uploads** : less important, but it limits the number of files you can upload at once

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important apasrt from php.ini setting is ,please check whether you have permission to write in that particular folder where you are uploading the image.

Answer (score -2):

Try add this in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
```

this value set maximum file to 100KB.

Comment: NO! The maximum file size is not a user input. It should be a constant or a server-side variable. A hidden input is easily changed by the user!